# Why IIS Server returns null baseUrl of ASP.NET CORE 5 MVC project, but returns true on local server?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0, request.servervariables

I am developing ASP.NET CORE 5 MVC project and I want to use server variables to send email and show the file on new tab. In my local machine I can get the host name but after publishing on IIS, I couldn't get the result.

**I am getting base url like this**

```
string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", @HttpContext.Request.Scheme, @HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.GetServerVariable("HTTP_HOST"));
ViewBag.url = baseUrl;
```

[image: result of ViewBag.url]

**I am using in razor page like**

```html
                           @if (@item.DOKUMAN1 == null)
                            {
                                <div class="col-sm-2 my-2">
                                    <a hidden href="@ViewBag.url/UploadedImages/@item.DOKUMAN1" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon ion-android-folder" style="font-size:25px;font-family:Calibri" src="~/UploadedImages/@item.DOKUMAN1"><b></b></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="col-sm-2 my-2">
                                    <a href="@ViewBag.url/UploadedImages/@item.DOKUMAN1" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon ion-android-folder" style="font-size:25px;font-family:Calibri" src="~/UploadedImages/@item.DOKUMAN1"><b></b></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" value="@ViewBag.url/UploadedImages/@item.DOKUMAN1"/>
                            }
```

[image]

I added images of debug results too.In local I can get the true result:
**http://localhost:16122/UploadedImages/1a78f896-6893-4079-a4d0-5a3387296ecb.mp4**  on local server, but on IIS Server result is ***http:///UploadedImages/1a78f896-6893-4079-a4d0-5a3387296ecb.mp4***.

> **Here is the result of local server**
> [image]

> **Here is the result of IIS server**
> [image]

How can I get the server base url ?

Comment: A possible cause is that your requests are being proxied, and ASP.NET Core doesn't "trust" headers such as `X-Forwarded-Host`, so they aren't being set. Also, ASP.NET Core 5 goes out of support today, so you should upgrade to ASP.NET Core 6. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: By using `Url.Something` or `LinkGenerator` directly, with a `HttpContext.Request.Host` argument?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet gives you the current host address :

```
string myDomainName =HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current was removed in ASP.NET Core :(